# How to split string using line endings as delimiter but keep the line endings in output (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, split, line-endings

I have a method that splits a string by various line endings

However this method removes the line endings in the new array. How do I preserve the different endings \r,\n,\r\n as part of the strings that are split?

> String[] lines = line.split("(\r\n|\r|\n)");

Desired Outcome

```
String Input = "test line 1\r\ntest line 2"
String[] Output = [0] = test line A\r\n
                  [1] = test line B
```

Comment: Use a lookbehind?

Comment: Look at `java.util.StringTokenizer`

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because your current input _already_ has a new line character in it, and hence the two lines would appear on separate lines.  Please edit your question and show us what the literal string output should be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good call. I meant to display it as elements in an array. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try splitting on a fixed width lookbehind:

```
String input = "test line 1\r\ntest line 2";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\r\n)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[test line 1
, test line 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the original string and see what follows each token, then add it back in.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this regular expression :`(?<=\\n)|(?<=\\r)(?!\\n)`